# mmap() cannot allocate memory when repeatedly mapping and unmapping one single page

Tags: c++, linux, mmap

I have read many SO (and other) questions, but I couldn't find one that helped me. I want to `mmap` two files at once and copy their content byte-by-byte (I know this seems ridiculous, but this is my minimal reproducibly example). Therefore I loop through every byte, copy it, and after the size of one page in my files, I `munmap` the current page and `mmap` the next page. Imo there should only ever be one page (4096 bytes) of each file be needed so there shouldn't be any memory problem.

Also, if the output file is too small, the memory is allocated via `posix_fallocate`, which runs fine. I a lack of memory space in the hard drive can't be the problem either imo.

But as soon as I am going for a bit larger files with ~140 MB, I get the `cannot allocate memory` error from the output-file that I am writing into. Do you guys have any idea how this is?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char file_input[] = "medium_big_file";
    char file_output[] = "foo_output";
    int fd_input = -1;
    int fd_output = -1;
    unsigned char *map_page_input, *map_page_output;
    struct stat stat_input, stat_output;

    if ((fd_input = open(file_input, O_RDONLY)) == -1 ||
          (fd_output = open(file_output, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0644)) == -1) {
            cerr << "Error on open()" << endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // get file size via stat()
    stat(file_input, &stat_input);
    stat(file_output, &stat_output);
    const size_t size_input = stat_input.st_size;
    const size_t size_output = stat_output.st_size;

    const size_t pagesize = getpagesize();

    size_t page = 0;
    size_t pos = pagesize;

    if (size_output < size_input) {
      if (posix_fallocate(fd_output, 0, size_input) != 0) {
        cerr << "file space allocation didn't work" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
    }

    while(pos + (pagesize * (page-1)) < size_input) {
      // check if input needs the next page
      if (pos == pagesize) {
        munmap(&map_page_input, pagesize);
        map_page_input = (unsigned char*)mmap(NULL, pagesize, PROT_READ,
          MAP_FILE|MAP_PRIVATE, fd_input, page * pagesize);
        munmap(&map_page_output, pagesize);
        map_page_output = (unsigned char*)mmap(NULL, pagesize,
          PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd_output, page * pagesize);
        page += 1;
        pos = 0;
        if (map_page_output == MAP_FAILED) {
      cerr << "errno: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
          cerr << "mmap failed on page " << page << endl;
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
      }

      memcpy(&map_page_output[pos], &map_page_input[pos], 1);

      pos += 1;
    }

    munmap(&map_page_input, pagesize);
    munmap(&map_page_output, pagesize);


    close(fd_input);
    close(fd_output);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The very first iteration of the loop attempts to unmap something that was never mapped, and passes a completely uninitialized pointer to `munmap`. Not once, but twice.

Finally, `munmap` expects a pointer to the mmap-ed memory, and not a pointer to a pointer to the mmap-ed memory.

The shown code fails to check the return status from `munmap`. If it did, it would've discovered that every call to `munmap` fails (hopefully, but if the first call happens to pass an aligned pointer, a chunk of the stack might end up being unmapped, with the ensuing hilarity), so the shown code just keeps allocating more, and more pages, and running out of memory.

You must fix both bugs.

Comment: Well, at least the OP provided a [mcve], so good job on that!

Comment: Indeed, it's sad what the times have become: a normal question deserves an upvote simply for being normal, and better than 90% of the others.

Comment: In theory, people asking questions *might* look at other questions and mimic the ones with more upvotes...

Comment: One can only hope... But, past experience shows that it's just a theory.

Answer (score 2):

You do not check the exit code of `munmap`. It fails. It fails because you do not need to take the address of the address. Replace:

```
munmap(&map_page_input, pagesize);
```

with

```
munmap(map_page_input, pagesize);
```

Because munmap fails, you run out of max number of mappings per process.

Answer (score 2):

munmap takes as first argument the **value** returned by mmap. In your code munpap receives a pointer to a variable containing it, so you are not actually unmapping the area. Just remove "&" in munmap call.